# Angular 2 show header only on page

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm new to angular 2 so please pardon me, 
how do i show header only when page isn't: "home or login or register route".

```
<header><header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer></footer>
```

i felt i'd try to get the route name and use and if statement but not show how. Please help

Comment: you can create a [service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service) that will set a boolean. The component that consume header will sub to the service and the template will looks something like this `<header *ngIf="showMe"></header>`.

Comment: Pls can you show me an example code

Comment: did you follow the link I provided ? You have even a live example : https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/cb-component-communication/ts/eplnkr.html

Answer (score 0):

app.component.ts

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
...
...

 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 showHeader: boolean = true;
 constructor(private router: Router) {}

 ngOnInit() {
  // listenging to routing navigation event
  this.router.events.subscribe(event => this.modifyHeader(event));
 }

 modifyHeader(location) {
   if (location.url != "/home" && location.url != "/login" && location.url != "/register" && location.url != '/')
   {
       this.showHeader = false;
   } else {
         this.showHeader = true;
     }
}
}
```

in app.component.html

```
  <header *ngIf="showHeader"><header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <footer></footer>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/jUIVOfNDVVCyw2gk1Ara?p=preview

Comment: the component where the header component has been used

Comment: i tried this, it loads just header and nothing else and every page i navigate to leads back to root directory.

Comment: showHeader must be initialize with true to be displayed by default, and then after you navigate to another page set showHeader to false to hide it

Comment: Doesnt work. i get this EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'HomeComponent'
Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'HomeComponent'
    at getOutlet

Comment: checkout the plunker i created.